# How do Fable 3 business partnerships work?

Tags: fable-3

I was exploring the random co-op feature and found a player that I got along with enough to start a business partnership. My first actions were to buy the local pawnbroker and a few other high-profit businesses. I've been saving gold for the good-side endgame and need a *lot* of gold to achieve a perfect ending.

When I bought the properties, the money was taken from my total and the owner is now listed as MyGamerTag & OtherPlayerGamerTag. Are these profits now going to be added to my account automatically? When I play? When my partner plays? When we're both in that world? My world?

Answer (score 5):

As I understand it business partnerships work a lot like Civil Unions ([source](http://majornelson.com/archive/2010/10/24/show-375-call-of-duty-black-ops-mp-star-wars-the-force-unleashed-ii-fable-iii.aspx)).  The goal is that a functional business relationship should have the same benefits as something like Marriage.  Namely:

- When you are a player form a partnership, it only takes effect when you are playing together.
- While playing together, every purchase made (by either player) is split evenly. So if Player A buys a house worth 10000 gold. Both players pay 5,000 gold. If one player only has 1000 gold, they spend all of it, and the other player spend 9000. Same for items.
- Income from properties, jobs, chests are split 50/50.
- When dissolving a partnership (or marriage) all joint properties are sold and the proceeds are split 50/50.  This happens whether or not you're in a game together.