# Is there any way to share previously purchased property in Fable 3?

Tags: fable-3

My wife and I are playing Fable 3 - we got married in-game, and entered into a business partnership. We both own properties. But we don't always play the game at the same time so we don't and out owning all of the same properties.

Short of selling/re-purchasing the properties while we're both playing, is there any way for us to combine the property we own?

Comment: To clarify, you want to put all your properties into the same joint venture when only one of you is around?

Comment: Yeah, that too. More specifically I was thinking of taking our existing property (e.g. we're playing on my quest and I want to share my property I purchased previously). But it would also be useful (if at all possible) to do that, too.

Comment: Did you figure out a (partial) answer on this yourself meanwhile? Could you share your co-op experiences in my question [When to (not) play Fable 3 in co-op mode?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/98038/88) Here's a related question I just found: [How do Fable 3 business partnerships work?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/10166/88)

Comment: My only answer - start co-op, and just start dumping then re-buying your properties. It was a bit of a grind, but that's all I could do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The only thing you can do is re-sell your property.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. Sold and re-bought everything. Took a while, but it worked.

Comment: Sorry, there's no other way.